# Panadas read_Excel to ignore blank rows

Tags: python

I have written a program which will read all the .xlsb files from [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/) and process them one by one.

I have some .xlsb files which has 286 lines with data and other 1 million blank lines. Which reading via Pandas' *read_excel* function, I want to ignore these blank lines.

```
df = pd.read_excel('/dbfs/mnt/sheets/XXX/YYY.xlsb',engine='pyxlsb',sheet_name='sheet1',header=1,dtype=str,keep_default_na=False,usecols=finalColumns,converters= {'Valid From (if different than document)': pd.to_datetime,'Valid To (if different than document)': pd.to_datetime})
```

Still it is running the whole day, but no result.

How can I read only data rows and ignore blank rows?

Comment: If you know which rows are blank you can pass `skip_rows` as a parameter to `read_excel()` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: @medium-dimensional Thanks for the reply. No. I used keep_default_na=False in my case too. it is not helping me

Comment: @DPM Thanks for the reply. skip_rows is to skip rows from starting. my rows towards end and also i can't implement this as i am going apply a generic code for 1000 excels. that is to read it and process

Comment: Does it have to be `read_excel`? Why not use `read_csv` which has a `skip_blank_lines`?

Comment: @DPM all the documents are excel. to convert those to CSV i need to do read_excel first